# Determine if a body of text contains valid words or just "gibberish"

Tags: text, cpu-word, statistics

I'm interested in ideas for identifying whether any given body of text contains valid, actual words, or just gibberish text.

The problem I run into immediately is that it needs to be language-agnostic, as the data we deal with is highly international. This means either a statistical approach, or an extremely large, multi-lingual hash table approach.

The multi-lingual hash tables seem straightforward, but unwieldy and possibly quite slow. (Or at the very least, a compromise between speed and accuracy.)

However, I don't really have a background in the statistical approaches that would be useful to me in this situation, and would very much appreciate anyone's experience or input, or any other suggestions.

Comment: If you use any kind of statistical analysis it will be just as easy to produce "gibberish" that matches the criteria.

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping for something that could at least offer a threshold. Reading around, calculating entropy seems like it might be the way to go, and that at least can help divide up large sets of text into "likely actual language" and "unlikely actual language".

Comment: I don't think a multi-lingual hash table becomes inevitably unwieldy and slow. Storing a big international dictionary of billions of words should not be much of a problem nowadays, and dictionary lookups also stay fast even for big dictionaries. The problem you must solve is to find a big word list for each of the languages you want to support. And: how do you define gibberish? Do you want to separate meaningful text from text which contains valid english words but does not make any sense? That's sometimes not easy for a human, good luck :-)

Comment: @DocBrown - no, we're happy simply to say "if a document is primarily filled with strings like 2340ois;adfgq34p5;adfkg;a90234p2o3 it's gibberish, but if a document reads like it was written by a three year old on LSD, we'll call it valid."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ngram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) analysis to compare your text with an example text.  This could either be on characters or words.

Google's [NGram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/) can help visualize what I mean.  As an example, if I search for "haddock refrigerator" then there are no occurrences (e.g. it's gibberish), whereas "stack overflow"  shows occurrences came into prominence once computers did.

Comment: I looked into n-grams. I've actually got to hand the full Google n-gram set, and whilst it's 850GB of data, it only covers a dozen languages. It's a good idea, and judging by the responses I'm seeing here, it might be the approach I end up taking.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know or can you determine the language of the document?  I don't think loading a dictionary for a single language and calculating the % of valid words would be inordinately slow or memory intensive.

How accurate does it need to be?

Comment: I was trying to do it without language detection, primarily because a lot of the documents can be multi-language. In terms of accuracy, ideally we'd have a threshold value we can play around which we can then use to make it more accurate as needed.